# Updating only specific rows within the lowest value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update different rows in my table.

I got a table called: **table_price_product**

this table contains all the information related to different products

> NOTE: inside this table you will see different rows for the same
>   product (or not) because it contains all the prices for all products (old and new ones)

Every **item_code** has a different "request_id", the newest row will have the highest value.

Take a look at this table:

```
|ITEM_CODE |PRICE    |START_DATE_ACTIVE |END_DATE_ACTIVE   |INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG    | STATUS| REQUEST_ID |
|'99342435'|'9999'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937536'  |
|'91123323'|'1049.67'|null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42455454'  |
|'89992424'|'18799'  |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42886567'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937524'  |
|'91123323'|'900.67' |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42455447'  |
|'89992424'|'17499'  |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42886541'  |
```

This is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50a0db)

> I want to create an UPDATE script in order to modify the item_codes within the lowest request id

In this case, the **item_code**: '99342435' has 2 rows: one with the **request_id** = '42937536' and the other one with the **request_id** = '42937524'. I would like to update the row with the lowest request_id and set the attribute **'status' = '150'**

[image]

---

I would like to obtain this output:

```
|ITEM_CODE |PRICE    |START_DATE_ACTIVE |END_DATE_ACTIVE   |INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG    | STATUS| REQUEST_ID |
|'99342435'|'9999'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937536'  |
|'91123323'|'1049.67'|null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42455454'  |
|'89992424'|'18799'  |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42886567'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |150    |'42937524'  |
|'91123323'|'900.67' |null              |null              |I                     |150    |'42455447'  |
|'89992424'|'17499'  |null              |null              |I                     |150    |'42886541'  |
```

I tried to do something like this but it did not work.:

`max(request_id) over (partition by item_code) as max_request`

Can help me to solve this?

EDIT#1: i'm using Oracle database

---

---

EDIT: I could have this scenario:

```
|ITEM_CODE |PRICE    |START_DATE_ACTIVE |END_DATE_ACTIVE   |INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG    | STATUS| REQUEST_ID |
|'99342435'|'9999'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937536'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937524'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937512'  |
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
|ITEM_CODE |PRICE    |START_DATE_ACTIVE |END_DATE_ACTIVE   |INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG    | STATUS| REQUEST_ID |
|'99342435'|'9999'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937536'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |150    |'42937524'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |150    |'42937512'  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

Update using `min()`

```
update table_price_product
set status = '150'
where REQUEST_ID in
(
    select 
       REQUEST_ID
    from
    (
        select
            ITEM_CODE,
            min(REQUEST_ID) as request_id
        from table_price_product
        group by
            ITEM_CODE
    ) val

);
```

After update statement when you do `select` as following then you get your output as expected.

```
select *
from table_price_product
```

Output:

```
| ITEM_CODE | PRICE   | INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG | STATUS | REQUEST_ID |
| --------- | ------- | ------------------ | ------ | ---------- |
| 99342435  | 9999    | I                  | NEW    | 42937536   |
| 91123323  | 1049,67 | I                  | NEW    | 42937536   |
| 89992424  | 18799   | I                  | NEW    | 42937536   |
| 99342435  | 9800    | I                  | 150    | 42935836   |
| 91123323  | 900,67  | I                  | 150    | 42930236   |
| 89992424  | 17499   | I                  | 150    | 42936936   |
```

---

EDIT: I could have this scenario:

|ITEM_CODE |PRICE    |START_DATE_ACTI

```
VE |END_DATE_ACTIVE   |INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG    | STATUS| REQUEST_ID |
|'99342435'|'9999'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937536'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937524'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937512'  |
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
|ITEM_CODE |PRICE    |START_DATE_ACTIVE |END_DATE_ACTIVE   |INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG    | STATUS| REQUEST_ID |
|'99342435'|'9999'   |null              |null              |I                     |NEW    |'42937536'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |150    |'42937524'  |
|'99342435'|'9800'   |null              |null              |I                     |150    |'42937512'  |
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying!. I'm checking it out :)

Comment: I got a question: are you really searching through all the different item_codes and comparing their request_id?

Comment: @Student_new please check the updated answer. I have provided demo as well.

Comment: @Student_new let me know what you think about it.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working but do not fully understand what you did in the update statement at all

Comment: @zealous: You are making this more complicated than necessary and you are even relying on the fact that either two different items cannot have the same request number, or that a new request number always updates all items, which we don't know to be the case. You can simplify the first query to `where (item_code, request_id) in (select item_code, min(request_id) ...`.

Comment: You are welcome. But do you think you have changed the query according to my comment? Because you haven't.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I did but I am getting error `You can't specify target table 'table_price_product' for update in FROM clause`. here is the fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pYYXSX7tbbnpWgm9b45qoW/0.

Comment: That is MySQL. It is correct that MySQL has this flaw, but even in MySQL there is a proper solution (see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mvduQbtJrBbcduhC5uuNM5/1). You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/, they have more DBMS to choose from.

Comment: @zealous The problem here is that i am just changing the status for the lowest request_id.. there could be many different rows referring to the same item_code. I wanna turn all the rows, not just the one with the lowest request_id

Comment: @Student_new please take a look at this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o3XkhkhM1hZNin123vEWe7/0. it will convert all lowest `request_id`.

Comment: Yeah, it works. just one thing: what is *rnk > 1* really doing? What about "var"?

Answer (score 1):

We can try using an update join here:

```
UPDATE table_price_product tpp1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ITEM_CODE, MIN(REQUEST_ID) AS MIN_REQUEST_ID
    FROM table_price_product
    GROUP BY ITEM_CODE
) tpp2
    ON tpp1.ITEM_CODE = tpp2.ITEM_CODE AND
       tpp1.REQUEST_ID = tpp2.MIN_REQUEST_ID
SET
    STATUS = '150';
```

The logic here is that we use the `tpp2` subquery to scope only records for each item code which have the minimum value for the request ID.  Then, we update the status for those records only.

Comment: Hey dude, thank you for replying!. I'm checking it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to update the rows where not exists an older row for the product:

```
update table_price_product pp
set status = 150
where not exists
(
  select null
  from table_price_product older
  where older.item_code = pp.item_code
  and older.request_id < pp.request_id
);
```

If you are worried about speed, you may want to provide this index:

```
create index idx on table_price_product (item_code, request_id);
```

For completeness sake: Saying that no older row exists can also be expressed as: You want to update the rows where the request ID is the minimum for the product. Hence:

```
update table_price_product pp
set status = 150
where (item_code, request_id) in
(
  select item_code, min(request_id)
  from table_price_product
  group by item_code
);
```

This query, too, can benefit from the suggested index.

Comment: Hey dude, how are you?
The problem is that i am not interested in the minimal request only; take a look: i have updated my question

Comment: In your request you are still asking the same question: How to update the rows with the least request ID per item. And our replies still answer this. The only thing you changed is that you added an example that contradicts what you are saying, because in that example you are updating a row that has not the least request ID for that item. And I have no idea by what new rule you've picked that row.